# concat as resource collection in zip not working?

Tags: ant

I'm trying to use `<concat>` as a resource collection in a `<zip>` task and, according to the documentation, this should work.  I'd like to do this because some of the files I want to include in the zip need to have some properties expanded, so I will also add a `<filterchain>` to the `<concat>` to do this.  I'd prefer to do it directly rather than copying to a temp location (with property substitution) and including the copy in the zip file.

However, I can't seem to get `<zip>` to correctly use the `<concat>` element.

A simplified example of what I have so far:

```
<zip destfile="target/dist.zip">
   <concat>
      <fileset file="CHANGES.txt" />
   </concat>
</zip>
```

This creates a zip file containing several directories all named `concat (C:` (obviously this is on a Windows machine).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague and I came up with the answer by looking through the `<zip>` and `<concat>` source.  There are really two answers:

1. `<concat>`'s implementation of the `ResourceCollection` interface is odd, but we understand why.
2. There's a way around that.

For #1, while `<concat>` is a `ResourceCollection` (like `FileSet`), under the hood it returns as the name of single `Resource` it contains a hard-coded value:

```
"concat (" + String.valueOf(c) + ")";
```

Look familiar?

The name of resources is normally ignored--except by `<zip>` and its related tasks, which uses the resource name as the `ZipEntry` name.  Since `<concat>` returns the odd-looking name, that's what we get in the zip file.

I haven't quite figured out why I get multiple entries, but it doesn't matter: the observation leads to a convoluted solution.

Since I know the name of the `ZipEntry` I want to create, I can use a `<mapper>` to give the `<concat>` resource a name.  Here's what I came up with in all its glory:

```
<zip destfile="target/distribution.zip">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <exclude name="target/**" />
        <exclude name="CHANGES.txt" />
    </fileset>
    <mappedresources>
        <concat>
            <fileset file="CHANGES.txt" />
            <filterchain>
                <expandproperties />
            </filterchain>
        </concat>
        <mergemapper to="CHANGES.txt" />
    </mappedresources>
</zip>
```

As my colleague says "In Ant every problem can be solved using a mapper."

This only works for Ant 1.8+ because `<mappedresources>` was added in that release.

I'm going to post some comments to the Ant mailing list and suggest a couple of enhancements:

1. Allow a resource name to be specified as an attribute on `<concat>` when it's being used as a `ResourceCollection`.
2. Throw an exception (and don't create a synthetic value) if `getName()` is called without having a value specified.
3. Finally, though not directly related, I do wish `<expandproperties>` could take a `<propertyset>` so I can control which properties get substituted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the final zip to contain a single file or multiple files? As far as I can see, using concat (when done successfully, which isn't done above) would produce a single file, the result of concatenation of all files in the resource collection.

If you want multiple files rather than concatenation, I think intermediate copy is what you'll need.

From Ant manual for the concat task:

> Since Apache Ant 1.7.1, this task can
>   be used as a Resource Collection that
>   will return exactly one resource.

Comment: The final zip is going to contain multiple files, which I'm getting using a `<fileset>` (not shown in my example).  The one file I want to do property substitution on I want to use the `<concat>` with a specified `<filterset>` (also not shown).  The example I gave simply doesn't work as I expected it would based on the documentation, which you've quoted, regardless of adding any other files or doing the property substitution.

Comment: Fair enough thanks. Your expectation was unclear from original question but I understand now. I played a bit with concat within zip. Behaviour is strange alright.